# Smart Tv application with transparent background : showing Tv broadcast in the background

Tags: javascript, css, html, samsung-smart-tv

**in a smart Tv application (Samsung , LG ...)** is it possible to show the Tv input stream/broadcast in the app background ? 
meaning : to overlay the channel/content being watched with the app User interface ?

in the Samsung 2011 smart Tv emulator i'm seeing that if i set the app body background to be transperent :

```
body
{
    width: 960px;
    height: 540px;
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

i can see the Tv input Stream (changing scenery pictures) , but not in the 2012/13 emulators.

Is it possible to get the same affect on a real TV (and on the 2012/13 emulators) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a Ticker App. For this type of application put the value of ticker tag in the config.xml file as 'y', here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget>
    <cpname itemtype="string"></cpname>
    <cplogo itemtype="string"></cplogo>
    <cpauthjs itemtype="string"></cpauthjs>
    <ThumbIcon itemtype="string">icon/icono106.png</ThumbIcon>
    <BigThumbIcon itemtype="string">icon/icono115.png</BigThumbIcon>
    <ListIcon itemtype="string">icon/icono85.png</ListIcon>
    <BigListIcon itemtype="string">icon/icono95.png</BigListIcon>
    <category itemtype="string"></category>
    <autoUpdate itemtype="boolean">n</autoUpdate>
    <ver itemtype="string">0.100</ver>
    <mgrver itemtype="string"></mgrver>
    <fullwidget itemtype="boolean">n</fullwidget>
    <type itemtype="string">user</type>
    <srcctl itemtype="boolean">y</srcctl>
    <ticker itemtype="boolean">y</ticker>
    <childlock itemtype="boolean">n</childlock>
    <videomute itemtype="boolean">n</videomute>
    <dcont itemtype="boolean">y</dcont>
    <widgetname itemtype="string">App</widgetname>
    <description itemtype="string"></description>
    <width itemtype="string">1280</width>
    <height itemtype="string">720</height>
    <author itemtype="group">   
        <name itemtype="string"></name> 
        <email itemtype="string"></email>   
        <link itemtype="string"></link>           
        <organization itemtype="string">
        </organization>
    </author>
</widget>
```